# Is all knowledge trivia? (Edit - and should the trivia tag be removed?)

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I recently submitted a puzzle with the 'knowledge' tag. It was automatically changed by the system to 'trivia'.

When did this happen?

Do we now consider all knowledge to be trivia?

Should the 'knowledge' tag simply be deleted if it is no longer allowed?

EDIT 13 Oct 2015

For clarity, here is a definition

> trivia
>
> details, considerations, or pieces of information of little importance
>   or value. "we fill our days with meaningless trivia"
>
> https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=trivia+definition

**Proposal**

Since all trivia is knowledge but not all knowledge is trivia, I suggest that the more general 'knowledge' would be a more apt tag to keep. The trivia tag is too restrictive and should no longer be the default. Instead I propose that 'knowledge' should.

Comment: The [knowledge] tag is a synonym of the [trivia] tag, so everything automatically gets tagged as [trivia].

Comment: How would you differentiate between the two? (The synonym could be made to point the other way, too. That might make more sense.)

Comment: @Emrakul I would interpret **trivia** to relate to snippets of "interesting fact"-type information, but **knowledge** expects some deeper level of expertise or understanding of the subject-matter (or appropriate use of your favorite search engine).

Comment: I've added a definition of trivia to my answer. I have also added a proposal.

Comment: Okay. For the interim, I've deleted the tag synonym. I still think we should work out exactly what should happen with those tags, though. I'm in favor of merging and/or synonymizing trivia into knowledge, but we'll ultimately go with whatever you all think will work best.

Comment: It seems to me that if a concrete subject matter can be named, then that ought to be the tag - preferable to 'trivia' in my opinion, and much more than 'knowledge'.

Answer (score 4):

No, not all knowledge is trivia.  Math is knowledge, but I expect nobody thinks we ought to do away with the 'math' tag.

I think that 'knowledge' is far too broad to be useful as a tag. Who is going to be searching for it and why?

Particularly for a question such as this [USA geography puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8678/usa-geography-puzzle) , I do not see how a user gets any benefit from the addition of the 'knowledge' tag.

Comment: That is a fair point but it doesn't explain why currently 'Knowledge' is automatically converted to 'Trivia'.  We don't automatically convert 'Knowledge' to 'Math' -- why convert it to Trivia?  In either case we are going from the general to the particular and that seems unreasonable.

Comment: Does the presence of the knowledge tag not suggest that a certain depth of knowledge will be required to solve it?

Comment: The presence of the 'geography' tag already suggests that, doesn't it?